# Android App Widget permissions

Tags: android, permissions

My very simple app currently does not ask the user for any permissions at all when they install it. I want to keep it this way but I really need to add a widget.

I was looking over the StackWidget Example (http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/) and I noticed that in the manifest they have:

```
<service android:name="StackWidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
        android:exported="false" />
```

That permission there "BIND_REMOVEVIEWS", I haven't seen before. If I were to build off of this example and include that service with that permission, will the user now be notified that my app requires a permission before it can be installed/updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

`<uses-permission>` elements are what trigger the user to be notified about permissions that your app is *requesting*.

`android:permission` indicates that you are *defending* a component with a permission that some other app (or, in this case, the firmware) must hold. Since you are not requesting the user grant you a permission, the user is not bothered with the `android:permission` attribute.

So:

- `<uses-permission android:name="com.commonsware.permission.SHAVE_YAK" />` is asking the user "may I shave your yak?"
- `android:permission="com.commonsware.permission.SHAVE_YAK"` is telling a third-party app "the user must have agreed to allow you to shave the user's yak"

<sub>note: no actual yaks were harmed in the creation of this answer</sub>

Comment: is `android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"` should be put in the `receiver` or `service` ?

Comment: @mori: Neither, usually.